# How to display HTML in a different order to the source code

Tags: html, seo

We have a client who is very fussy about their seo and wants the html to appear in a very specific order in the source. This is fine until that order is completely different to the order that they wish the parts of the page to render.

This is integrating into a cms which makes it somewhat harder.

Currently, the only method that I have come across is to position these elements absolutely so as to have complete control over display vs source order. This obviously comes with its own set of problems when coupled with dynamic content.

We are unable to use css3 for the site as it must be the same across all platforms. CSS3 has some very nice features to achieve exactly what I want but its off the table.

Are they any other methods to allow the content to be ordered differently in the source compared to display. There are 4 - 5 parts per page that need ordering.

Comment: Is it specifically where your client wants content first then header/navigation?  Or can you offer any other specifics or example code you've already been working with?

Comment: Yeah, to give you an idea of the ordering: the html will read - #homepage-1, #homepage-2, #homepage-3, #homepage-4, #header, #footer and the actual page order will be #header, #homepage-3, #homepage-2, #homepage-1, #homepage-3, #footer. Does that make sense?

Comment: Could you explain a little more to me about why he is wrong to want the important content at the top of the page. I am not especially familiar with SEO practices as a lot of it seems strange and counter intuitive to me.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me like your client doesn't understand how SEO works with today's crawlers. Five years ago, this was a different story; You better have had your important links up top in the code. Today, that's not the case, even though some still swear by it.

Regardless of that, reordering your source is a horrible idea in terms of accessibility. Screen readers read the source in order, thus making the site harder to read and navigate for those using assistive technologies.

So, my recommendation to you is try to educate your client that content order in the source does not matter with today's search engines and it severely hurts accessibility when you start to reorder content in a fashion that doesn't make logical sense. In other words, don't do it.

Comment: Cheers Michael, I will try my best to do this as I cannot see a viable method to do what I am being asked to do within a CMS. The guy is very good at seo but I do question a lot of the smaller things that he asks  us to do simply because I find it very hard to believe that google could represent the value of a page within a search engine if it put such an emphasis on things that the best sites do not do and would find hard to adhere to without creating dull and over simplistic design.

Answer (score 1):

These two posts demonstrate implementing this "SEO trick".

[Markup Hierarchy – Advantages in SEO | HTML/CSS Tutorials | Web Design Tutorials and Front-end Development Blog by Soh Tanaka](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/markup-hierarchy-advantages-seo/)

[Navigation Markup After Content | CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/2519-navigation-markup-after-content/)

I particularly like this [comment](http://css-tricks.com/2519-navigation-markup-after-content/#comment-54923) (quoting Google):

> “Our search engine also analyzes page
>   content. However, instead of simply
>   scanning for page-based text (which
>   can be manipulated by site publishers
>   through meta-tags), our technology
>   analyzes the full content of a page
>   and factors in fonts, subdivisions and
>   the precise location of each word.”
>
> Source: [Google Technology
>   Overview](http://www.google.com/corporate/tech.html)

Sounds more like guess work than proven method.  I'm inclined to think this trick is a big waste of time.

---

I think this [Matt Cutts: SEO Tips for Bloggers – Place keywords early on page](http://www.seoracle.com/seo-tutorial-optimization/matt-cutts-seo-tips-for-bloggers-place-keywords) is where the theory comes from or at least garnered further support.

Comment: Thats great mdmullinax. Thanks very much. I have spoken to the chap I work with and we are trying to impress upon the client that the order within the html is of little relevance to google. Giving preference to sites which are able to use CSS hacks to manipulate content doesn't seem like something google would allow.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the details of just how you want them ordering, I'd recommend that you use floated divs to get things into the right place. Sometimes the code order affects the display order, but at other times it doesn't if divs are being "floated" to different parts of the page. It's hard to be specific without knowing the layout you want.

Comment: Hi Paul, 2 a couple of divs this is not an issue however as mentioned in the notes above (in one of the response replies), the display order and html source order bear no relation to each other at all.